# Linking mixed FORTRAN and C++ in the Visual studio 2008 environment

Tags: c++, visual-studio, linker, fortran, windows-vista

I am calling a C++ function from FORTAN using ISO_C_Binding module. I can compile and link the Fortran and C++ files using MINGW g++ and gfortran command line option using the command sequence

```
gfortran -c main.f90

g++ -c print_hi.cpp
```

for compiling and for linking I can use the gfortran option and including the C++ standard libraries as

```
gfortran main.o print_hi.o -o main -lstdc++
```

which work absolutely fine. 
Now my questions is how can I do the same in the visual studio environment. In case of simple C we will just include the print_hi.o file in the additional dependencies in the linker but if I only include this C++ file (print_hi.o), it gives errors like

```
 Error LNK2010: unresolved external symbol _ZSt4cout referenced in function _print_hi
```

So I guess I need to give the path to the C++ libraries in my FORTRAN project as we are doing in the command line MINGW case but I don’t know how to do this.

PS: I am using windows Vista, with intell visual fortran compiler professional edition 11.1 in Visual studio 2008 and C++ in Visual studio 2010 in the same computer.

Answer (score 0):

This MSDN articles can help you:
[Mixed-Language Issues](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270932%28VS.60%29.aspx)
and 
[Mixed-Language Programming with C++](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa270933%28v=VS.60%29.aspx)

Only pay attention that all this concerns VC++ 6.0.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, actually my question is not related with the programming, which is the main concern in the link provided. it is rather about the setting or including some C++ libraries in the Visual studio.

Comment: VC++ 6, damn that's ancient. And I wouldn't even call that a compiler for c++

Answer (score 0):

Go to Project Properties -> Linker -> Input -> Additional Dependencies, and enter the library names there.

Comment: thank you very much for your reply............Which libraries names should I enter in the additional dependencies; my C++ object file name is already there. As I already mention my FORTRAN is working in VS2008 while C++ is working in VS2010 so how can I cater for this (I mean should i copy shome libraries files to my project folder or to give some path etc ???????)

Comment: I'm afraid I don't have much experience with Visual C++ or VS2010. There's probably a C++ runtime library in your system path, so you shouldn't need to copy anything to your project folder, but merely add the appropriate stdc++ library name in Additional Dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you **statically** build with the gfortran run-time library 
Try gfortran -static-libgfortran (-c or -S) -f2003 yourfortransource.f90 .  You should get an object file with an .o extension.

Then bring the object file over to your MS compiler.  Compile your C/C++ source code to an object file only.  Last do a normal build with the two object files together.  Do this with the command line compiler to make sure it works.